# Removing about 50,000 rows without getting 505 errors

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, inner-join

I'm trying to run the sql query below but I'm getting a 505 error after some long time wait. The wp_posts table holds much more than 50,000 rows...the purpose being to remove duplicates posts which are about 50,000 rows

```
DELETE bad_rows.*
FROM wp_posts AS bad_rows
INNER JOIN 
(
     SELECT post_title, MIN(id) as min_id
     FROM wp_posts
     GROUP BY post_title
     HAVING count(*) > 1
) AS good_rows 
ON good_rows.post_title = bad_rows.post_title
AND good_rows.min_id <> bad_rows.id;
```

Any idea on how to have this optmized and run ?

Comment: Could you just drop the table then recreate it?

Comment: the purpose is not to remove all rows but only duplicates posts

Comment: What about a select on the tables, compare with PHP, then query a delete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't think you need to use a sub-query. This will select all pairs of posts with the same titles.

```
SELECT a.id, b.id
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_posts b 
ON a.post_title = b.post_title
WHERE a.id > b.id
```

If you want to keep the oldest post, delete all posts with id a.id. If you want to keep the newest post, delete all posts with id b.id.

---

So, to keep the oldest post:

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_posts b 
ON a.post_title = b.post_title
WHERE a.id > b.id
```

To keep the newest post:

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_posts b 
ON a.post_title = b.post_title
WHERE a.id < b.id
```

Comment: The following errors were reported:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE a.id <> b.id' at line 7

Comment: Oh, `HAVING` comes after `WHERE`. My bad.

Comment: No problem. If it answered your question, click the tick to the left of the post to mark it as the best answer :)